# HTTPS security is compromised error. How to fix?

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, embed, security

[Click on href](http://northsideupc.com/media/) - on this page i has embed the iframe. Its iframe contents links. If i go to playlist tab and try to click on pictures in console of IE9 i see:

> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is IE's new way of warning about mixed content (HTTP and HTTPS resources on a secure page).

Fabio

Comment: But its new way is blocked work of my site! (sorry for my English)

Comment: just add an extra S to all http references... for example: httpS://www.example.com

Comment: Why it is occurs... On my site has no httpS iframes or something like that ^)

Comment: @Nikoole Mind sharing what the issue was and how you fixed it?

Comment: @Shredder answer checked as TRUE... If Parent page https, children must be https too.

Comment: Ouch. What about embedded google maps (as in displaying a location on a website's contact us page)?  Those require a `https://www.google.com/maps/embed...` address.  Whats up with that?

Answer (score 1):

This is an Internet Explorer error when it encounters mixed content (or what it thinks may be mixed content). Usually the error message also specifies which file is at fault, as in

`SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://example.com/example.html`

If you link to any images, JavaScript or CSS files from an https site you need to do so using https.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what caused the error was a javascript call to

```
document.write("something");
```

After I removed this script block the exception was no more thrown.

Comment: Stefan, just to confirm: does it mean if using https protocol, i can not use document.write?