# QuickSight dashboard in not rendering in iframe

Tags: amazon-web-services, internet-explorer, iframe, amazon-quicksight

We are trying to render the Amazon QuickSight dashboard in the `iframe`. We have created the embedded URL and rendered them in the iframe. The dashboard is being rendered in all browser except IE. I am using using IE 11.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to load mixed type of contents causing this issue in IE browser.

Your main page is using **HTTPS** protocol where some other contents using **res://**. If possible for you than you can try to use **HTTPS** for all the contents.

You can try to enable **Display mixed content** option in

> IE options -> Security tab -> Custom level -> Display mixed content

[image]

It may help to solve this error.

References:

(1) [HTTPS security is compromised error. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168132/https-security-is-compromised-error-how-to-fix)

(2) [Handling Mixed (HTTPS/HTTPS) Content](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/06/22/handling-mixed-httpshttps-content/)